# Whats the exact purpose of releasing netty's message?

Tags: java, netty

What does releasing a message `((ByteBuf) msg).release();` exactly do in netty and what happens if we don't release message like the code below:

```
    @Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    //received message
    ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
    
    //message sent to remote peer without releasing
    ctx.writeAndFlush(msg);
}
```

Comment: If ByteBuf is received from the Nett's pool, release() returns it back to pool. If you don't return it then there will be memory leak

Answer (score 1):

Basically the "consumer" of the `ByteBuf` is responsible for releasing it. In your example the consumer is `ctx` which will hand the buffer over to the  previous handler and so on. At the end it will hit the "transport itself" which will release the buffer once it was written.

If the "consumer" of the `ByteBuf` miss to release the buffer and not hand over the buffer to another component it will leak. As netty uses a pool for `ByteBuf` it means that at some point you will run out of memory.